# jQuery won't load updated images

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is anyone able to determine, how to stop the jQuery caching the image that it grabs, and displaying the same image around and around again?

Basically the image is been re-uploaded every 5 seconds, as it acts as a webcam (if you check the time stamp on the bottom right of the image, you can tell if it's been updated or not)

http://colourednoise.co.uk/scripts/index.htm

Thank you

(sorry I forgot to hit paste for the code)

```
$(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgs = ['http://www.ramseycommunityradio.co.uk/images/webcam.jpg', 'http://www.ramseycommunityradio.co.uk/images/webcam.jpg']
    $("#webcam").attr('src', imgs[1]);
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#webcam").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            $el.attr('src', $.inArray($el.attr('src'), imgs) === 0 ? imgs[1] : imgs[0]);
            $el.fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: please include your code here, that way it will be helpful to other people

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876551/jquery-get-doesnt-receive-latest-version-of-file-on-server/13876579

Comment: Please edit your post to include your code as comments don't keep formatting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code:

```
var imgs = ['http://www.ramseycommunityradio.co.uk/images/webcam.jpg', 'http://www.ramseycommunityradio.co.uk/images/webcam.jpg']
    $("#webcam").attr('src', imgs[1]);
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#webcam").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            $el.attr('src', $.inArray($el.attr('src'), imgs) === 0 ? imgs[1] : imgs[0]); 
// this condition is redundant, it will ultimately give the same result always
// because imgs[0]==imgs[1]

            $el.fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 2000);
```

as far a JQuery is concerned you are **not** changing the SRC attribute (JQuery knows nothing about the content of the image). Try using two *different* names in the server-side like `webcam0.jpg` and `webcam1.jpg` and alternating between them.

Comment: This hit the nail on the head! Took me a minute or two to see what was going on but it now makes sense. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could try appending a changing query string onto the URL, this should stop caching if that is indeed your problem. I've seen this done with a time stamp here: [how to generate and append a random string using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967975/how-to-generate-and-append-a-random-string-using-jquery)

So each time you generate an image you do:

```
var qs = (new Date).getTime();
var url = 'http://www.example.com/images/myimage.jpg?' + qs;
$(el).attr('src',url);
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick is t append a random query string URL which causes the image to reload from the server. The code could be something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var img = $("#img").get(0);
    img.src = img.src.replace(/\?.*/, "") + "?" + Math.random();
}, 5000);
```