# Implementing cross-domain post with bookmarklet

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Basically, I have an app to create lists with items associated to them. I'm trying to enable my app to accept cross-domain post with a bookmarklet to create an item from any website that I visit. I'm new to both rails and jQuery and any help will thus be much appreciated!

Right now, i receive a 200 OK back, the first time I press the bookmark. The second time, I receive a 304 error. However, no item is created.

items_controller.rb

```
def create
    @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:list_id])
    @item = Item.create!(params[:item])
    @item.wishes.build(list_id: @list.id)
    if @item.save
        flash[:success] = "Item created!"
        redirect_to @item
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

bookmarklet.js

```
alert('Loaded');

document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>');


(function($)
{

    alert( $('title').text() );

var dataObj = {
    'remote_image_url': "http://developer.android.com/assets/images/dac_logo.png",  
    'title':    $('title').text(),
    'link': "http://omfg.dk",
    'list_id':  5,
    'commit':   "Add wish"
};

$.ajaxSetup({
  type: "POST",
  // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
    },
  crossDomain: true
});

$.post('http://localhost:3000/items', dataObj, function(data)
{
    //alert('ADDED!!!');
});


}(jQuery));
```

bookmark

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');script.src='http://localhost:3000/assets/bookmarklet.js';document.body.appendChild(script);%7D)()
```

Furthermore, I have the `rack/cors` gem installed and setup up like this:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
   allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*',
        :headers => :any,
        :methods => [:get, :put, :delete]
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

304 is not an error, it says that the resource is cached an not modified. There are a few ways to fix this:

1. Modify your web server implementation to not cache and always return a 200.
2. Append a random string to the end of the url so that it is not cached. Here's an example: [how to generate and append a random string using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967975/how-to-generate-and-append-a-random-string-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks - great insight! Do you have any idea on why an item isn't created?

Comment: The item isn't created because the request isn't making it to your backend. The 304 is essentially a "short-circuit" that instructs the browser to use its cached response value rather than execute the request on the server-side.